# How do I specify width and height of Android GridLayout cells in relative measures?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to figure out how [GridLayout](http://android-developers.blogspot.no/2011/11/new-layout-widgets-space-and-gridlayout.html) works, but one thing I can't figure out from the documentation is how or if one can control the size of the grid cells.

Say I want a two by two grid where each cell occupy exactly 25% of the screen real estate (half height, half width) - can I do this?

With LinearLayout I would accomplish this by nesting two horizontal LinearLayout's in one vertical and then assigning a **weight** of 1 to all elements. GridLayout does not support the weight property though.

Comment: Hehe I was expecting that question. There are two reasons I still want an answer to this. 1: Academic. 2: I think the code will be easier to read when using GridLayout

Answer (score 21):

There's two properties  android:layout_columnWeight and layout_rowWeight which works like layout_weight in LinearLayout. This is supported in API 21. For older android devices, use the GridLayout from the v7 support library.

Those properties will allow you to adjust the width/height of column base on the value you assigned to each column. The formula goes like this  (column_weight/ sum_of_column_weight) * gridLayout_width = column_width.

Here's an example which is a gridview with 2 rows and 2 columns evenly spread out, each takes 50% of the weight and height of the grid.

```
<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:columnCount="2"
>

    <TextView
        android:text="SEARCH FEE"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
     />

    <TextView
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:text="SEARCH FEE"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
     />

    <TextView
        android:text="SEARCH FEE"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:text="SEARCH FEE"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        />
</GridLayout>
```

Comment: Sadly, the childs don't fill the cells.

Comment: This code is missing `android:layout_width="0dp"` and `android:layout_height="0dp"` for the cells

Comment: No, you don't want to use `layout_width` or `layout_height` here. `GridLayout` children aren't resized to fit the rows and columns, so if you say an item is 0dp that's what you'll get.

Comment: Note that weight is only supported from API 21. But you can use the support library, using :  compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:24.0.0'

Answer (score 12):

it looks like setting it as you'd like should be fairly straightforward according to the documentation:

```
android:rowCount='2'
android:columnCount='2'
```

and in the children set

```
android:layout_columnSpan="1"
android:layout_rowSpan="1"
```

[This](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html) reference also mentions stretching:

> To prevent a column from stretching, ensure that one of the components in the column does not define a gravity.

Which would seem like a solution to keep the rows and columns in a 50:50 ratio without resizing according to content

Comment: I'm afraid that wasn't enough. This code: https://gist.github.com/4633342 produced this result: http://i50.tinypic.com/b3sn5z.jpg. Desired result for this case: http://i46.tinypic.com/2h32a36.png (ms-paint'ed)

Comment: Of course that code would! You're specifying the layout_width and height in pixels. Take out any `android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"` and see how that looks. **Edit** after your desired case had been put up: what you need to then do is to put objects inside your linearlayout, but you can't specify both the height and width of the linearlayouts, **and** tell them to fill the gridview

Comment: If I put objects inside the layouts, the grid sizes to the size of the objects. I want it the other way around. If I in my example remove the laoyut_width/height, the LinerLayout elements get zero size - leaving a white screen. If I set it to "fill_parent", the first layout (red) fills the entire screen, not only 25%.

Comment: A quick note on fill_parent: after API 8 it's been deprecated, and recommended to use match_parent. You could try using `android:layout_gravity='fill'` in the LLs and seeing what that does

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this?

Comment: No I had to move on so I went for the nested LL's in my solution. I haven't had the time to test layout_gravity='fill'.

Comment: Have now tried layout_gravity='fill'. No luck. LinearLayouts are the solution. This question explains it well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4961355/percentage-width-in-a-relativelayout

Answer (score 9):

It would be something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:columnCount="2"
    app:rowCount="2">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="1"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        app:layout_rowWeight="1" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="2"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        app:layout_rowWeight="1" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="3"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        app:layout_rowWeight="1" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="4"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        app:layout_rowWeight="1" />

</android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
```

Comment: How does setting all the cells width and height help with this?

Answer (score 2):

There is a helper method inside the GridLayout:

```
GridLayout.LayoutParams params = new GridLayout.LayoutParams();
            params.columnSpec = GridLayout.spec(GridLayout.UNDEFINED, 1, getAlignment(Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, true), 1);
item.setLayoutParams(params);

private GridLayout.Alignment getAlignment(int gravity, boolean horizontal) {
        int mask = horizontal ? HORIZONTAL_GRAVITY_MASK : VERTICAL_GRAVITY_MASK;
        int shift = horizontal ? AXIS_X_SHIFT : AXIS_Y_SHIFT;
        int flags = (gravity & mask) >> shift;
        switch (flags) {
            case (AXIS_SPECIFIED | AXIS_PULL_BEFORE):
                return horizontal ? LEFT : TOP;
            case (AXIS_SPECIFIED | AXIS_PULL_AFTER):
                return horizontal ? RIGHT : BOTTOM;
            case (AXIS_SPECIFIED | AXIS_PULL_BEFORE | AXIS_PULL_AFTER):
                return FILL;
            case AXIS_SPECIFIED:
                return CENTER;
            case (AXIS_SPECIFIED | AXIS_PULL_BEFORE | GravityCompat.RELATIVE_LAYOUT_DIRECTION):
                return START;
            case (AXIS_SPECIFIED | AXIS_PULL_AFTER | GravityCompat.RELATIVE_LAYOUT_DIRECTION):
                return END;
            default:
                return GridLayout.FILL;
        }
    }
```

Normally this is only accessible thought reflection.

And the smaller version:

```
params.columnSpec = GridLayout.spec(GridLayout.UNDEFINED, 1, GridLayout.FILL, 1);
```

Answer (score -1):

I have made my own 3 * 3 board for tic tac toe using below dimensions.
This code is for the first row. I did the same for other rows too.

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
    android:id="@+id/gridLayout"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@drawable/board"
    app:columnCount="3"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/blackboard"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/blackboard"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/blackboard"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/blackboard"
    app:rowCount="3">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        app:layout_column="0"
        app:layout_row="0"
        app:layout_rowWeight="1"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        app:layout_gravity="center"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        app:layout_column="1"
        app:layout_row="0"
        app:layout_rowWeight="1"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        app:layout_gravity="center"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        app:layout_column="2"
        app:layout_row="0"
        app:layout_rowWeight="1"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        app:layout_gravity="center"/>
```