# GridLayout overflows the screen

Tags: android, android-layout, grid-layout, android-gridlayout

I have images in a Grid Layout. However the Grid Layout rows overflow the screen. I think the image widths are not the cause of problem. If I delete the images, the grid layout lines still overflow.

How can I solve this?

Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/myGridLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:columnCount="2"
    android:rowCount="2"
    tools:context="com.example.orhan9.mdtransitionanimation.MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/papagan"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="0"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/papagan"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/goril"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="0"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/goril" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/okuz"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="1"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/okuz" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ordek"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="1"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ordek" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnTransition"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="transition animation" />

</GridLayout>
```

Layout screen:

[image: Layout screen]

Comment: Use gridview instead of gridlayout, pass adapter with gridview, you can also take recyclerview to support latest api,

check below link : 
https://www.journaldev.com/13792/android-gridlayoutmanager-example

Answer (score 0):

I might found couple of ways to help you out:

1. Try use a *Linearlayout* to warp your images, set its *width* & *height* and inside it put your images like suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23890588/long-text-on-button-messes-up-gridlayout-rows/23890689#23890689) (Their solution is with *TextView* but you can do the same with your *Imageview*).
2. Set your image size to be specific size (in dp).
3. Try to use `android:layout_rowWeight` and `android:layout_columnWeight` like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14500677/how-do-i-specify-width-and-height-of-android-gridlayout-cells-in-relative-measur).

And here is a quick tutorial that might help you understand better the *Grid Layout*:  [Grid Layout by Example](https://blog.stylingandroid.com/gridlayout-part-1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
You can do this to avoid overflows the screen because in your case you have to declare height and width
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/myGridLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:columnCount="2"
        android:rowCount="2">
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/a"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ffff"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/b"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_row="0"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ffff"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout

        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/c"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ffff"/>


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/d"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ffff"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```