# Grid with different item height and width

Tags: android, android-listview, android-widget, android-gridview

can someone help me and tell me is this possible in android. I need to have in my app a gridview alike widget, but with different item height and width, like this:
[image]

So is this possible, and if so, what can I use to achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: I think [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10812552/heterogeneous-gridlayout) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11863329/gridlayout-and-row-column-span-woe) you have an answer :)

Comment: So you want to copy pinterest style? :)

Comment: @PareshMayani I think pinterest does not have different item width, does it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you need a work around or you can say a third party Library named as "**AndroidStaggeredGrid**"

You can check it on [here](https://github.com/etsy/AndroidStaggeredGrid)

Answer (score 0):

@Darko,

Yes, it it possible to do like this in Android.

There are many ways to implement this. As you said GridView cannot be used to achieve this. For a normal user this will appear has grids.

Ways:

1. Use fragment for each and every "grid" you can see and each fragment will have its layout to display either 2 or 3 images in grid (No gridview is required here too). Use ImageViews as usually.
2. If the layout design is same, then you can define a single layout with internal design in the same format. Each row with imageviews - This is not encouraged by the way.
3. Design layouts for each and every format of design per row. Inflate each particular row to a list (using custom adapter). Based on position in getView() you can control which row design to be added to list. Inbuilt scroll in ListView, so no problem!

I suggest you to go with number #1 or #3. Using fragments you will have better control.

If you come to know any better idea, please share!

Answer (score 0):

It's StaggeredGridView

You can find an implementation at https://github.com/bulletnoid/StaggeredGridView

Answer (score -3):

It's possible using GridLayout. More details in the link.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html

Comment: I did answer the question with this line: "It's possible using GridLayout". That was the exact question by OP.