# Android complex layout design advise

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-fragments, android-emulator

I'm suppose to implement a complex layout for Android dashboard activity as shown in the following image.

[image]

Here for some cells multiple text views should be added like this, 
Eg:

[image]

Here the texts of some text views will be loaded from a web service using Async tasks. Only one image view should be click able.
I want to know that what is the best way to implement this type of complex layout in Android.
I have tried to use linearlayouts withing lianearlayouts to implement this but it is huge mess and lot of complex. Then I tried to use tablelayouts with lianearlayouts but it is also getting more complex. Then I thought of doing this using grid views with linearlayouts but I'm wonder how to do this exactly.
I'm still in learning stage, I just want an advice what is the best way to implement this layout what type of layouts should I use and where. I don't need complete implementation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can give GridLayout a try.

Comment: You mean linear layouts withing grids to add multiple text views ?

Comment: Do you have responsive elements ?

Comment: I meant the one described here. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayout.html

Comment: @NickF Only one image view should be click able others are not responsive

Comment: can table layout be useful? try it

Comment: Have you tried just a plain old RelativeLayout?  GridLayout is more suited for, well, a uniform grid.  With RelativeLayout you can tell each view exactly where it needs to be.

Comment: Check this out https://github.com/maurycyw/StaggeredGridViewDemo

Answer (score 7):

These kind of problems can be solved very easy using Android Percent Support Lib,

[image]

checkout gist: 
https://gist.github.com/shekarrex/5458f697c02e5619b0e2

Answer (score 3):

see GridLyout that will help you..
[GridLayout and Row/Column Span Woe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11863329/gridlayout-and-row-column-span-woe)

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Working_with_the_Android_GridLayout_in_XML_Layout_Resources

Answer (score 2):

**Update:** As we know the percent support library is deprecated from API level 26. `ConstraintLayout` is the new way to achieve the same flat xml structure.

[**Updated Github Project**](http://code2concept.blogspot.in/2015/08/android-percent-support-lib-sample.html)

**Updated Samples:**

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fifty_thirty"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#ffff8800"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/fifty_fifty_text"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_default="percent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.5"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.5" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#ffff5566"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/fifty_fifty_text"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_default="percent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/fifty_thirty"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/fifty_thirty"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.5" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Deprecated**
Any one need a simple demo to use percent support library.

> [CODE and CONCEPT HERE.](http://code2concept.blogspot.in/2015/08/android-percent-support-lib-sample.html)

```
<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fifty_huntv"
        android:background="#ffff8800"
        android:text="50% - 50%"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        style="@style/STYLE_PERCENT_TV"
        app:layout_heightPercent="50%"
        app:layout_widthPercent="50%" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/comp2_twenty_fifty_tv"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/fifty_huntv"
        android:background="#ffff5566"
        android:text="20%-50%"
        style="@style/STYLE_PERCENT_TV"
        app:layout_heightPercent="20%"
        app:layout_widthPercent="50%"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/comp2_ten_fifty_tv"
        android:layout_below="@id/comp2_twenty_fifty_tv"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/fifty_huntv"
        android:background="#aa3628cc"
        android:text="30%-50%"
        style="@style/STYLE_PERCENT_TV"
        app:layout_heightPercent="30%"
        app:layout_widthPercent="50%"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/century_50_tv"
        android:layout_below="@id/fifty_huntv"
        android:background="#aacacc46"
        android:text="50%-100%"
        style="@style/STYLE_PERCENT_TV"
        app:layout_heightPercent="50%"
        app:layout_widthPercent="100%"
        />
</android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
```

WithIn styles.xml

```
 <style name="STYLE_PERCENT_TV">
        <item name="android:height">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:width">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">25sp</item>
    </style>
```

Github Project HERE

[image: percent complex design]

Answer (score 1):

If I need to implement such a layout I would split it to 3 parts:
1. One row from top to the red TextView in your screenshot.
2. Left column from orange "2 TextViews" till the bottom.
3. Right column with green and grey TextViews.

For each part you have at least 3 choices:
1. If the part has some serious logic I would use [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) because they have it's one life cycle.
2. If the has small logic and you don't want to implement all inside your activity, I would 
use a [custom View](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html).
3. If just want to split your layout xml check the [include](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html) tag.
4. You can use any permutation of 1 - 3, and split the layout in different way that fits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is you can use the **Fragments** and **include** tag for adding the other xml layout