# Android Implement responsive Layout without using nested Linearlayouts

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, responsive-design, android-linearlayout

The problem I have is that I can't figure out how to create a certain layout without using nested LinearLayouts with weights (cause Android keeps suggesting not to use them).
I know that you can use a bit of nested layouts if your logic is to just display info. But I would prefer to find a solution to make my layouts completely responsive for the different screensizes.

I'm developing an application for some specific devices with a screen resolutions between 4.0 and 5.0 inch. I don't mind that on the bigger ones the font type will be smaller orso. I just don't want to make a layout for each device. All the devices are running Android 4.4.X or higher.

One of the layouts I want to achiev is something like this:
[image: Layout example]

For now I made this with a LinearLayout for the blue sections.
Then inside each blue layout a linear layout for the red sections.
And inside each red section another linear layout for the one where I need to split it into half the width (50%). All of the LinearLayouts are using the logic of weightsum and the children layout_weight.

I tried it already with GridLayout and TableLayout but I'm not getting the result I want.

What is currently the best way to implement the layout for these devices (I don't need it to work for tablets etc)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sdk 23 support library includes layouts that allow for specifying width ans height in percentages, including PercentRelativeLayout, which is probably your best bet here.

See, for example, the currently un-accepted answer at 
[Android complex layout design advise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19521952/android-complex-layout-design-advise/31102079#31102079)

Comment: This is a very interesting feature that I'm defenitly gone look into for other projects. But for this question I need it to work under kitkat.
Thank you for the answer.

Comment: As I mentioned, the *support* library has this feature, which means that you can use it with older versions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Grid layout  or tableview

go to this link:

http://androidexample.com/Table_Layout_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=74&aaid=98

Comment: you'd better explain why your answer solves his problem , thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

use this dependency for using full responsive activity using percentages

```
implementation("androidx.percentlayout:percentlayout:1.0.0")
```