# how to layout images

Tags: android, image, android-layout

I have a lot of images in `scrollview`, I would like to know how to layout them so they would be seen the same on different resolutions. Like if I rotate screen some images would fill the gap.(All activity is only images)

Comment: Ok, I will you can post it as answer :)

Comment: Hello Did you tried ?

Comment: Sorry friend, have not time right now, will definitely try and report tomorrow, thank you for your patience :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `GridLayout`.

Check [Heterogeneous GridLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10812552/heterogeneous-gridlayout),[GridLayout and Row/Column Span Woe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11863329/gridlayout-and-row-column-span-woe).

It might helpful for you.

Comment: But Grid Layout is for ice screem sandwich, yes? And I need something for lower ones like 2,3,6

Answer (score 1):

This issue is behond displaying an image on a gridView but rather about memory limitation and caching(recycling and reusing etc..)
Take a look at this link [Displaying Bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html) and try to download a sample on the left called BitmapFun.zip