# GridLayout(Not GridView) : How to create Items With different Heights through xml

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-gridlayout

I have fragment with a view like this

[image]

Inside this grid layout my item  must be arranged like this

[image]

you can see the items have different heights . even the space between each rows  are  different .I try to achieve this through giving row spans . but all my logic gone wrong

I refer these links : [Link 1](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2007353&seqNum=8) ,[Link 2](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/11/new-layout-widgets-space-and-gridlayout.html), [Link 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11863329/gridlayout-and-row-column-span-woe)

But my ideas are not helping me . can anyone suggest me how to achieve this

EDIT :After accepting the answer

```
<LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.35">

</LinearLayout>

<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:rowCount="20"
    android:columnCount="1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_gravity="fill">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Name"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="EditText"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Space 
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <Space
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_rowSpan="1"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_rowSpan="4">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Address"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:lines="4"
            android:text="EditText"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
           />

        <Space 
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <Space
        android:layout_row="7"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_row="8"
        android:layout_gravity="fill">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Email"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>


        <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="EditText"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingLeft="30dp"
            android:src="@android:drawable/arrow_up_float"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <Space
        android:layout_row="9"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_row="10"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_rowSpan="6">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="About Me"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:lines="5"
            android:text="EditText"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Space 
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <Space
        android:layout_row="16"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_rowSpan="3"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_row="19"
        android:layout_gravity="fill">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Nick Name"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="EditText"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
      <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingLeft="30dp"
            android:src="@android:drawable/arrow_up_float"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</GridLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.30">

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can you handle that with two or three layout? if yes so you need `getItemViewType` and `getViewTypeCount` for creating this

Comment: @shayanpourvatan are you mentioning gridView

Comment: yes , sorry i didn't see `GridLayout` , Link 3 not helped you? what is the problem with that?

Comment: @shayanpourvatan i try with rowspan the item didn't expand, I try changing the layout_gravity also . but didn't work

Comment: can you post your xml?

Comment: @shayanpourvatan I had posted sample xmml i tried you can see the second edit text didn't expand

Comment: @Haresh i posted the xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Try this way,hope this will help solve your problem...

<LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.35">

    </LinearLayout>

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:rowCount="20"
        android:columnCount="1">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_gravity="fill">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Name"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="EditText"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <Space
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_rowSpan="1"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_row="3"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_rowSpan="4">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Address"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:lines="4"
                android:text="EditText"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <Space
            android:layout_row="7"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_row="8"
            android:layout_gravity="fill">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Email"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="EditText"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <Space
            android:layout_row="9"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_row="10"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_rowSpan="6">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="About Me"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:lines="5"
                android:text="EditText"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <Space
            android:layout_row="16"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_rowSpan="3"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_row="19"
            android:layout_gravity="fill">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Nick Name"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="EditText"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </GridLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.30">

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: thanks for your effort . Can you do me a little more help i need to add an image view after email and nickname text view .I achieve that i will post the xml . can have look on that and tell me is there any better way to achieve that??

Comment: have you need put it after Nick Name and Email EditText or TextView ?

Comment: so why you gave left padding to this images and why use Space where no image are required ?

Comment: i want align edittext parallel and there must be a space between edit text and image for that i give padding for image view . so in order to achieve the similar view for edittexts i use space where images not required

Answer (score 0):

//you need to do with `wieghtsum`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"

    android:weightSum="125" >

    <View
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="35" />

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="65" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="30" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Actually in need help in arranging items inside grid layout the second image