# I want to design row span like this in android

Tags: android

I want to design the same structure present in the image below in android can anyone help please! I found this in asp.net design but in android I don't find this sort of structure . I want to have column spans in gridview but in android people are saying it is only possible with gridlayout, is there any possibility to have column spans in android gridview please let me know.

[image: click here to see the img]

Comment: `TableLayout` does not support `row spans`, only `column spans`. Use `GridLayout` supports both row and column span

Comment: try to inflate custom layout inside any parent layout like linearlayout.

Comment: Thanks for your reply..Actually I'm using a gridview is it possible to have row spans in that??

Comment: @lakshmi see this help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11863329/gridlayout-and-row-column-span-woe

Comment: In an Android Table -- TableRow -- Textview has android:layout_span="number"  -- https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableRow.LayoutParams.html  -- which Defines how many columns this child should span