# Make android horizontal LinearLayout fit column in GridLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-gridlayout

I am trying to make a view that contains some elements from left to right order and a button, that attached to right top corner with fixed size. My current layout is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:columnCount="2">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/Image1"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:src="@drawable/image_src"
            android:visibility="gone" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Text1"
            android:text="SampleText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:gravity="center" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/Button1"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:src="@drawable/imageBtn"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle" />
</GridLayout>
```

When text is short everything seems to be ok

[image: When text is short - everything is ok:]

But the problem is that text can be very long, and it overlaps button.

[image: Not ok image]

How can I make button always visible and text wrapped exactly on the left corner of it?

Comment: share your expected output screenshot

Comment: give specific sizes to your views to make sure that they don't overlap . you can do it using your xml or via code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GridLayout and Row/Column Span Woe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11863329/gridlayout-and-row-column-span-woe)

Comment: Not sure but, can u put weights for views in linear layout and try?

Comment: You can use Linear Layout with weight and weight sum instead of grid layout. Just post a screenshot of the expected output then can suggest you the best option.

Comment: Can you add screenshot for your requirement and what you get now?

Comment: Is it compulsory to use grid layout? Because this same design you can achieve easily with RelativeLayout.

Comment: No. I just need the layout as on first screenshot. But instead of first image there can be other controls (run-time determined)

Comment: as told by @ReadyAndroid, you should have to prefer to use `RelativeLayout` or `LinearLayout`, you can achieve what you want by using any of these layouts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using RelativeLayout. Check below one in your xml layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/Button1"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/Button1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/Image1"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Text1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:text="SampleText sdfsd sd sdf sdfs  sdfsd fsf fsdf sd s dsfs sfs sfs sdf s fsdf sdf fsdf  sdf sf sd fsdf sfsdf sfsd ffs sdf sdf sfsdf sfs sdfs sfsdfs sfs sf sfs fsfsf sf ssf "
            android:textSize="16sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Worked, but I had to add right margin for text - or it got overlapped with a button.