# Create a staggered grid like the given image

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to achieve this view:

[image]

This is the partial view , I can have view vertically merged with 2 cells or horizontally merged 2 cells or single small view.

This view can scroll vertically

Please help me to get this.

Comment: checkout following link : http://abhiandroid.com/materialdesign/recyclerview-as-staggered-grid-example.html

Comment: @sapna , I have checked this code view are arrange only vertically  but you can check i have synchronized view vertically as well as horizontally

Comment: Hope This Helps : https://inducesmile.com/android/android-staggeredgridlayoutmanager-example-tutorial/

Comment: Have a look at `GridLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create this layout by using nested `LinearLayout` with attribute `layout_weight` and `weightSum`. To make this layout `scrollable`, use `ScrollView` as a root layout.

**Here is an working example:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!-- ROW1 -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="#ff0000">

        </LinearLayout>

        <!-- ROW2 -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2">

            <!-- ROW2 COL1-->
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#00ff00">

            </LinearLayout>

            <!-- ROW2 COL2-->
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:weightSum="2">

                <!-- ROW2 COL2 CHILD1-->
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="96dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#0000ff">

                </LinearLayout>

                <!-- ROW2 COL2 CHILD2-->
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="96dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#0000ff">

                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <!-- ROW3 -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2">

            <!-- ROW3 COL1-->
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#fff000">

            </LinearLayout>

            <!-- ROW3 COL2-->
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#fff000">

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <!-- ROW4 -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2">

            <!-- ROW4 COL1-->
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#ff00ff">

            </LinearLayout>

            <!-- ROW4 COL2-->
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:weightSum="2">

                <!-- ROW4 COL2 CHILD1-->
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="96dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#00ffff">

                </LinearLayout>

                <!-- ROW4 COL2 CHILD2-->
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="96dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#00ffff">

                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

**You can also use `GridLayout` to achieve this view.**

Here is a good [tutorial](https://inducesmile.com/android-tutorials-for-nigerian-developer/understanding-grid-layout-in-android/) about `GridLayout` and some stackOverflow [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11863329/gridlayout-and-row-column-span-woe).

Hope this will help~